# Cannot run ActiveMQ Artemis broker

Tags: jms, activemq-artemis, messagebroker

I'm trying to run the broker but I recieve this message. I succesfully created the broker so I don't know why this is happening.

Screenshot of cmd error here:

[image: 1]

I don't understand what `NO_ARTEMIS_OOME_DUMP` is.
The files that it says it cannot find (`bootstrap.xml`, `management.xml`), but they exist in one of the folders.
I added the artemis folder to the PATH.
How do I fix this?

I tried restarting, reinstalling, creating another broker... nothing works.

Comment: What version of ActiveMQ Artemis are you using?

Comment: It appears there are some special characters in your path after `C:\Users\Hadas\Desktop`. Can you try using a path without special characters?

Comment: Hey Justin, thank you! I opened up my computer after taking a break and the broker was no longer there (I have no idea how, I might have been spending so many hours trying stuff I didn't even notice.) So I created a new path that wasn't in Hebrew and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears there are some special characters in your path after `C:\Users\Hadas\Desktop`. I suspect that the ActiveMQ Artemis Windows start script is choking on these characters. Try creating a new path without the special characters. That should work.

Also, ensure you're using the [latest release](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/download/) of ActiveMQ Artemis as it has a fix for [ARTEMIS-4057](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-4057) which impacts the Windows start script.